# Undefind function pid/1 - Elixir

Tags: elixir

I'm following along an old video for learning about processes. I'm trying to send a ping but I'm getting back this error with my test. `lib/ping_test.ex:4: undefined function pid/1` I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as I'm not that familiar with Elixir yet. Here is my code:

```
defmodule Ping do
  def start do
    receive do
      {:pong, pid} -> send(pid {:ping, self()})
    end
  end
end
```

## Test

```
test "it responds to a pong with a ping" do
  ping = spawn_link(Ping, :start, [])
  send ping, {:pong, self}
  assert_receive {:ping, ping}
end
```

## Error

```
lib/ping_test.ex:4: undefined function pid/1
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Missing comma after `pid` in `Ping.start/0`?

Comment: Whoops yep you were right.